# Wordpress -Limit a User(etc Author) to only access a Plugin, not rest

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, admin

Is it a plugin or some modification in PHP i can do to make a Author only access a certain plugin and maybe one specific page i have made.

Example:
3 users - They are Authors and will be able to make polls and add them to a page(etc Polls). I dont want them to be able to see, edit anything else.

I have tried many of the "popular" plugins, but they don't support a specific page.

Answer (score 0):

Adminimize plugin could be effective.